# Are "kind" and "sort" synonym in "all kinds and sorts of people"?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

I am reading Norman Lewis's book *Word power made easy*. At one place the author says,

> "Words that describe all kinds and sorts of people..."

Here if "kind" and "sort" mean the same thing then the above sentence literallg means,

> "Words that describe all kinds and kinds of people.."

This is quite confhsing. Please explain.

Comment: Tautology like this is very common in English, especially in traditional fixed phrases and legal use--*over and above*, *time and tide*, *high crimes and misdemeanours*. It make the phrase slightly more emphatic and comprehensive. I'd be surprised if the use weren't just as common in other languages.

Comment: @StoneyB - I agree with everything in your comment, but just wanted to add that this particular instance doesn't strike me as very smooth. I think "kinds of" and "sorts of" are open-ended enough that no tautology is needed, and, personally, I don't care for this particular wording so much.

Comment: @J.R. I'm sorta kinda in agreement, but . . .

Answer (score 3):

*Kind* and *sort* (and *variety*, and *type*, etc.) are names for groupings (typically of noun phrases),
according to some shared criterion.

- *It's the most common/expensive **kind/sort/type/variety/model** of positronic brain defibrillator.*

Etymologically, *kind* is a noun from [the Proto-Indo-European root **gen*-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf) 'give birth to, be born, offspring', along with words like *king, kin, gonad*, and *gentle*, while *sort* is a verb from *sors, sortis-* ‘lot, condition.’ It refers to the common activity of sorting objects (and by extension, events) and features in many idioms and phrasal verbs.

From *a kind/sort of cookie* to *kind/sort of a cookie* is not much of a jump in meaning, but the grammar is different for *kind* and *type*, and for them alone.  *Sort* and *kind* have each developed quantifier-like idiomatic extensions with *of* (*sort of* and *kind of*), both meaning 'close to; approximately'. And these constructions can modify anything at all, even verbs. These are both so common that they have their own eye-dialect spelling contractions  -- *sorta* and *kinda*.

- *She got sort of mad ~ She sort of got mad* ~ *She got sorta mad ~ She sorta got mad*.
- *She got kind of mad ~ She kind of got mad* ~ *She got kinda mad ~ She kinda got mad*.

Naturally, when you're dealing with classifiers and other operators, it matters where you put them. In the sentences above, *kinda* and *sorta* can go before *mad*, meaning 'somewhat mad', or they can go before *got mad*, meaning 'did something that was close to getting mad'. These may in fact refer to precisely the same behavior, depending on the speaker's judgement about others' emotions.

This extension, by the way, doesn't happen with *type*, *model*, or *variety*:

- *It's a type of cookie,* **but** **It's type of a cookie* ~ **She got type of mad* ~ **She type of got mad*.

So in this regard, *kind* and *sort* **are** synonymous.

Answer (score -1):

For the phrase

> **all kinds** and **sorts** of people  =  **all kinds** and **all sorts** of people

> **[all kinds](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/all-kinds-of)** means "*a great number of*"

and

> **[all sorts](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/all-sorts)** means a "*wide variety of*"

as in

[image]

so the rephrasing of your original sentence would be

> Words that describe *many different* kinds of people.

This is different than @JohnLawler's answer since

> She got **kind of** mad = She was mildly angry

whereas

> She was **all kinds** of mad = She was furious